# ghc compile error but runghc works

Tags: haskell, linker, ghc

**UPDATE SOLVED**

I updated to Haskell Platform 2011.2.0.1   and GHC 7.0.3 and now it works!!

I have the following haskell file named "webscrap2.hs". I can execute "runghc webscrap2.hs" and it works fine. However when I compile the file I get an error.

webscrap2.hs

```
import Text.HTML.TagSoup
import Network.Curl (curlGetString, URLString)

main :: IO ()
main = do html <- openURL "https://github.com/languages/Haskell/created"
          let links = linkify html
          print links

openURL :: URLString -> IO String
openURL target = fmap snd $ curlGetString target []

linkify :: String -> [String]
linkify l = [x | TagOpen "a" atts <- parseTags l, (_,x) <- atts]
```

ghc --version

```
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.12.3
```

ghc -o webscrap2 webscrap2.hs

```
webscrap2.o: In function `r17I_info':
(.text+0x1fe): undefined reference to `tagsoupzm0zi12_TextziHTMLziTagSoupziParser_parseTags_closure'
webscrap2.o: In function `r17I_info':
(.text+0x204): undefined reference to `tagsoupzm0zi12_TextziStringLike_zdfStringLikeZMZN_closure'
webscrap2.o: In function `s1eb_info':
(.text+0x6fc): undefined reference to `curlzm1zi3zi7_NetworkziCurl_curlGetString_closure'
webscrap2.o: In function `s1ed_info':
(.text+0x927): undefined reference to `__stginit_curlzm1zi3zi7_NetworkziCurl_'
webscrap2.o: In function `s1ed_info':
(.text+0x933): undefined reference to `__stginit_tagsoupzm0zi12_TextziHTMLziTagSoup_'
webscrap2.o: In function `r17I_srt':
(.data+0x90): undefined reference to `tagsoupzm0zi12_TextziHTMLziTagSoupziParser_parseTags_closure'
webscrap2.o: In function `r17I_srt':
(.data+0x98): undefined reference to `tagsoupzm0zi12_TextziStringLike_zdfStringLikeZMZN_closure'
webscrap2.o: In function `s1ed_srt':
(.data+0xf8): undefined reference to `curlzm1zi3zi7_NetworkziCurl_curlGetString_closure'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any pointers what the problem might be?

Comment: thank you. I will try to swith to ghc7

Comment: are there any pointer on installing GHC 7.0.3 on ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: OK I found the following site: http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/haskell-platform.xhtml so the install should work.

Comment: Might be the versions of the packages you are using as well. I'm using curl-1.3.7 and tagsoup-0.12 so you might want to try updating them. But of course, updating GHC as well is a good idea :-)

Comment: Hi Adam! I updated ghc and haskell plattform and now it works. great! (if you make a regular answer I accept it..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try updating your GHC and the packages you are using, see if that helps.

Comment: thanks! your first comment got me on the right track. It works with ghc 7.0.3 (and the latest haskel frame work and of course doing the usual "cabal update" and "cabal install tagsoup")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have run `cabal install tagsoup` then it is a small matter of `--make`:

```
 ghc -o webscrap2 webscrap2.hs --make
```